# iterating over multiple columns and rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new to Pandas and desperately need help to modify my dataframe by comparing consecutive rows within multiple group pairings:

Dataframe example =

```
idData idStation idCast Pressure

1   1   1   1505
2   1   1   1506
3   1   1   1507
4   1   1   1508
5   1   2   1505
6   1   2   1506
7   1   2   1503
8   1   2   1504
9   2   1   1505
10  2   1   1506
11  2   1   1507
```

etc

I want to delete any rows where the Pressure value for that row is less than those above it, for each idStation and idCast pair (i.e. rows where idData = 7 and 8 need to be deleted). I don't want to compare different idStation & idCast pairs - i.e. first iteration of the loop would look through the Pressure record for idStation = 1, idCast = 1 and the second iteration of the loop would look through the record for idStation = 1, idCast = 2 etc). I have tried grouping by idStation and idCast, then looping over them and comparing row by row but this only modifies a copy, not the original dataframe and the changes are lost.

```
Stn_Cast_Group = Dataframe.groupby(['idStation','idCast'])
for name, group in Stn_Cast_Group:
        j = 0
        for i in range(1,len(group['Pressure'])):                     
            if group['Pressure'].iloc[i] < j:
                group['Pressure'].iloc[i] = np.nan
            else:
                j = group['Pressure'].iloc[i]
```

This labels the correct pressure values as nan (as I am unsure of how to delete the row) but only for the group view.

How would you create a copy of the dataframe (so as to have access to original and modified versions) and then delete the rows as mentioned above?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `boolean indexing` with the condition that for each group the `Pressure` value is not below the `.cummax()` for that group.

1. Use `.groupby()` to work on unique subsets of `['idStation', 'idCast']`.
2. For each of these groups, check if the current `'Pressure'` value is below the running `max` (`cummax()`), and return the inverse `boolean` (ie `False` if this the value is below). The result is returned from `groupby()` as `.values`.
3. Use the result of `2.` in `boolean indexing` to drop the rows that did meet the condition.

In `pandas` code, this looks like:

```
df[~df.groupby(['idStation', 'idCast']).apply(lambda x: x.Pressure < x.Pressure.cummax()).values]
```

to get:

```
    idData  idStation  idCast  Pressure
0        1          1       1      1505
1        2          1       1      1506
2        3          1       1      1507
3        4          1       1      1508
4        5          1       2      1505
5        6          1       2      1506
8        9          2       1      1505
9       10          2       1      1506
10      11          2       1      1507
```

You can also eliminate the `.apply()` step as suggested by @MaxU for a ~40% speed increase for the toy data:

```
df[df.Pressure >= df.groupby(['idStation','idCast'])['Pressure'].cummax()]
```

Comment: I think this version (without `apply`) should be faster: `df[df.Pressure >= df.groupby(['idStation','idCast'])['Pressure'].cummax()]`

Comment: Amazing! That worked like a charm. How does the first half of the condition 'df.Pressure' specify that you are talking about each idStation/ idCast group - it looks as though you are just specifying the entire Pressure column?

Comment: The `.groupby()` does this. Added some explanation above.